# GestureRecognizers doesnt work on Image but on StackLayout

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Please someone tell me why this markup doesn't fire the tap gesture?

**Not working**

```
<Image.GestureRecognizers>
    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped" NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
</Image.GestureRecognizers>
```

But this one does? And I did followed a very basic implementation from the Microsoft/Xamarin docs on how to add a `GestureRecognizer`.
If I switch to this markup it works perfect! Everything tested on  Android phone 7.0 API 24. I use the latest Xamarin.Forms 3.3.0 pre 3 nuget package.

**Working Markup**

```
<StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped"  NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
</StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
```

Comment: Looks like it's a known bug: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/3818

Comment: ok, and is there a patch or workaround? i mean its pretty basic and important that this feature works! I wanted and need to use Command on TapGesture and the only thing that works so far is a Tapped event handler on a stacklayout. I had to surround my image with a bogus stacklayout as a workaround but like i said its just a tapped event not a command... Any ideas on how to fix this issue or a workaround to use commands?

Comment: @MartinMightyMartLauzon why not just use the Command property on the tap gesture recognizer instead the Tapped property ?

Comment: I tried but it doesnt work. A Tapped event works and replacing this with a Command and CommandParameter fails to trigger the Command. It simply do nothing and trust me I tried a plain new projectg and add an image + tapgesturerecognizer copy paste from xamarin doc example.

Comment: It seems like Xamarin.Forms package has so many issues and bugs... I wonder why and how they get there. Fix something to introduce new issues... far from being a mature product/framework.